# ios : How to get photo url which is deleted in photo.app

Tags: ios, photo, assets, nsassert

I am having issue in my app, the app is photo related,

In my app I have required photo url which is deleted via Photo.app, is there any way to find in our app that which photo is deleted in photo.app

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

No practical way, I suppose you could iterate over the photo library before the deletion and then iterate over the photo library after the deletion to see what the changes were.

Comment: I have check Tidy app, that app at some how find if app is not open, but that app will provide notification some image added in photos app, i don't know how that app will do this without open app, that app will know in photo.app will update with new photos and give notification on lock screen.

Answer (score 0):

I do a similar thing in my "Chanda" app. The photos are stored in iPhone Photo Library and a link is stored in the database. I believe that if you delete the photo from the Photos app then you will get nil or something when trying to fetch the photo.

[Link a picture taken on my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18832853/link-a-picture-taken-on-my-app/18833009#18833009)

Comment: any idea about ALAssetsLibraryChangedNotification ?